# JSON.parse(stdout) of curl in hubot coffeescript giving undefined

Tags: json, curl, coffeescript, servicenow, hubot

Very new to coffeescript, I'm curling the API of ServiceNow to get information out and return it back to a chat. I'm struggling with parsing the JSON response though as it is coming back undefined, not sure what's going on:

```
snurl = '"https://companyname.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=number%3D' + snincmagic + '&sysparm_fields=number%2Csys_id&sysparm_limit=10"'
snpayload = '--request GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" ' + " --user 'username':'password'"
tixcurlhack = require "child_process"
tixcurlhack.exec "/usr/bin/curl #{snpayload} #{snurl}", (error, stdout, stderr) ->
  if error
    msg.send "Error: #{error.code} - #{stderr}"
  else
    jsonresponsedata = JSON.parse(stdout)
    incidentnumber = jsonresponsedata.result.number
    incidentsysid = jsonresponsedata.result.sys_id
```

but even though stdout contains the JSON, incidentsysid comes back as undefined:

```
      msg.send "stdout is: " + stdout
      msg.send "jsonresponsedata is: " + jsonresponsedata
      msg.send "incidentsysid is: " + incidentsysid

> incidentsysid is: undefined.
> jsonresponsedata is: [object Object]
> stdout is: {"result":[{"number":"INC0010689","sys_id":"acb09c8fdb65324063447aecbf96192a"}]}
```

Is there something obvious I should be doing here to get result.number and result.sys_id into their variables?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the JSON is being parsed OK, but you are accessing it wrongly:

```
> stdout is: {"result":[{"number":"INC0010689","sys_id":"acb09c8fdb65324063447aecbf96192a"}]}
```

Will be parsed to:

```
jsonresponsedata = {
  result: [
    {
       number: "INC0010689",
       sys_id: "acb09c8fdb65324063447aecbf96192a"
    }
  ]
}
```

So to access the number and sys_id you should use:

```
 incidentnumber = jsonresponsedata.result[0].number
 incidentsysid = jsonresponsedata.result[0].sys_id
```

Comment: That was exactly what was needed, thank you! I just learnt more about the syntax; the last json I was parsing did not have square brackets, so it contained no array. This one does so needs to be accessed via the array index... 

_Square brackets hold arrays_